# Android Studio not updating and projects are corrupted

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Few days ago I created a project which looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op8z6.png).

I thought that project was corrupted but since then whenever I created new projects they all looked like it I tried to delete caches but it did not fixed anything

I have a feeling it is because i have not updated my android Studio but whenever i try to Update this error [comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIfN0.png)

any idea whats going on. I would appreciate any help

Comment: Try deleting all AS related folders and reinstalling it from scratch

Comment: thank you for your suggestion I will do it rn

Comment: Reinstall android